# Can I make this string multiline?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I make the following javascript variable be multiline?

```
var newPage = $('<div data-role="page" id="link'+myvar+'" data-url="link'+myvar+'"><div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a></div><iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://www.example.com'+myarrayA[myvar]+'" style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%; background: white"></iframe></div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some ways you could simulate a multiline string in js:

- the plain old string concatenation method

```
var string = "first line " + 
             "second line " + 
             //...
             "nth line";
```

- the array join method

```
var string = ["first line ", 
             "second line ", 
             //...
             "nth line"].join('');
```

- and the slick, hacky, undocumented method (which works, although [it is not allowed by standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript#comment12930059_805113))

```
var string = "first line \ 
             second line \ 
             //...
             nth line";
```

I personally like the *join method* because it is valid javascript and gives you the power to insert characters between rows. For example, if you want to *export* your string as a multiline html paragraph, you can easily do smth like this :

```
var pContent = ["first line ", 
                "second line "].join('<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

```
var a = $('<div data-role="page" id="link'
+myvar+'" data-url="link'+myvar+'"><div data-role="header" \
 data-position="fixed"><a href="#" data-rel="back" \
data-icon="back">Back</a></div> \
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer? /embedded=true&url=http://www.example.com'
+myarrayA[myvar]+'" style="border: 0; position:absolute; \
top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%; \
background: white"></iframe></div>');
```

Comment: But be **very** careful, because if you leave a space after the \ it won't work

Comment: @NicoSantangelo: That explains the problem I was having with this method earlier. Thanks.

Comment: NicoSantangelo is right!

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

```
var newPage = $('<div data-role="page" id="link'+myvar+'" data-url="link'+myvar+'">' +
  '  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">' +
  '    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>' +
  '  </div>' +
  '  <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://www.example.com'+myarrayA[myvar]+'" style="border: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%; background: white"></iframe>' +
  '</div>');
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4GgTC/